# Save PDF to Documents (PDF is corrupted)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, pdf

I'm saving PDFs from JSON.  When I navigate to the File Path in the App Documents Directory to verify I have the right file, and try to open the PDF, **I can't open the PDF**, and I get this error:

[image]

[image]

The File Path is good, the document is there, but its just been corrupted or something.  I'd assume this is related to `NSData` but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

ViewController:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Downloading PDF Started");

    // Get selected PDF
    NSString *pdfSelected = self.pdfArray[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"PDFSl: %@", pdfSelected);
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfSelected]];
    NSLog(@"PDFData: %@", pdfData);
    NSString *pdfPath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld.pdf",@"savedPDF", (long)indexPath.row]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [pdfData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"PDF File Saved!");
        NSLog(@"PDF File Path: %@", pdfPath);
        // Save PDF path in defaults for evaluation in Details
        [defaults setObject:pdfPath forKey:@"cachedPDFPath"];
    });

});
```

JSON snippet:

```
  {
        "fname": "Nadene",
        "lname": "Feehan",
        "email": "nadene.feehan@gmail.com",
        "phone": "(152) 555-5321",
        "image": "http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Apple-logo-grey-880x625.png",
        "video": "https://github.com/versluis/Movie-Player/blob/master/Movie%20Player/video.mov?raw=true",
        "pdf": "http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_3.pdf"
    },
```

Console:

`PDFSl:http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_3.pdf`

`PDFDataLength: 2070`

`PDF File Path: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1/data/Containers/Data/Application/A/Documents/savedPDF0.pdf`

I also tried:

`NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfSelected] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&errorPDF];` but when I checked the console to see the error there was none `PDFDataError: (null)`

Comment: Can you show the contents of the console log (specifically, the results of the logging statements that you show)?  Also, when you log `PDFData`, can you also log the length of the data (i.e. `pdfData.length`)?  Also, if that doesn't show anything interesting, you might try using `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` in place of the more simplistic `dataWithContentsOfURL:` to see if you're actually, and successfully, downloading the data.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels No problem, just added the console log.  Does anything stand out to you?

Comment: Looks like the URL is locked if you're not signed in with your developer account; when I tried it w/out having signed in first, I get redirected to this page:  https://developer.apple.com/unauthorized/

You'll probably need to sort out how to handle users who aren't signed into their developer accounts (and, to make things more complicated, I believe developer.apple.com auto-signs you out after something like 20 minutes or an hour of inactivity), and it doesn't look like it's as straightforward as simply checking HTTP status/error codes.

Comment: To close the loop, the contents of developer.apple.com/unauthorized are just straight-up HTML, so a PDF parser is almost certain to crash.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels that makes perfect sense and I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to come across that without your help.  I think the only thing that would have helped was for me to magically get logged out of the developer account and then maybe I'd have understood what was going on.  Thanks!  If you post as answer I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the URL is locked if you're not signed in with your developer account; when I tried it w/out having signed in first, I get redirected to this page: developer.apple.com/unauthorized.  The contents are, as you might expect, pure HTML, and I'm guessing many, if not most, PDF parsers would crash if you send them HTML.

You'll probably need to sort out how to handle users who aren't signed into their developer accounts (and, to make things more complicated, I believe developer.apple.com auto-signs you out after something like 20 minutes or an hour of inactivity), and it doesn't look like it's as straightforward as simply checking HTTP status/error codes.